# How to annotate django queryest using subquery where that subquery returns list of ids from related model records

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have one database model, let's say `ModelA`:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
     field_1 = models.ManyToManyField(
         "core.ModelB", blank=True
     )
     user = models.ForeignKey("core.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     type = models.CharField(choices=ModelATypes.choices)
```

The `field_1` of `ModelA` is a many to many field that references `ModelB`.

```py
class ModelB(models.Model):
     uid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, I want to annotate the queryset to show the list of uid's from `field_1` based on some filter like get the list of `ModelB` uid's from `field_1` for all the ModelA records where user is in list of applicable user ids.

Example:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery
user_ids = [1, 2, 3]
result = ModelA.objects.filter(type="year").annotate(
     model_b_uids_list=Subquery(
         ModelA.objects.filter(user__id__in=user_ids).values_list("field_1__uid", flat=True)
    )
)
```

This gives error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. I tried using `ArrayAgg` function but that does not seems to be working.

I want the annotated field `model_b_uids_list` on ModelA to have a list of uid's from the field_1 from multiple applicable records on ModelA.

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to find any solution to achieving this using ORM in Django 3.x or earlier version. But Django 4.1 seems to solve this issue with the introduction of `ArraySubquery`.

The code below should work fine to solve this problem.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.expressions import ArraySubquery

user_ids = [1, 2, 3]
result = ModelA.objects.filter(type="year").annotate(
     model_b_uids_list=ArraySubquery(
         ModelA.objects.filter(user__id__in=user_ids).values_list("field_1__uid", flat=True)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making query so complex? if you just wanted to get the list of ModelB uid's from field_1 for all the ModelA records where user is in list of applicable user ids, so can't you do simply like this?

```
result = ModelA.objects.filter(type="year", user_id__in=user_ids).values(
            "field_1")
```

Comment: This will return the uid's applicable for one record. What if I want that for every ModelA record? I cannot run for loop and do this for every record. So, my next option will be to annotate every record on ModelA with the list of uid's.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the subquery *through* the `ArrayAgg` function, as such

```
ArrayAgg("other__id", filter=Q(other__name__icontains="x"))
```

This is a full example with data that you can play with.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import *

class Student(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)


class Course(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    students = ManyToManyField(Student, related_name="courses")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Course({self.title!r})"

c = Course.objects.create(title="Agg-ravating Queries")
c.students.add(Student.objects.create(name="Woody"))
c.students.add(Student.objects.create(name="Buzz"))
c.students.add(Student.objects.create(name="Sid"))

qs = Course.objects.filter(title__icontains="queries")
qs = qs.annotate(
    names=ArrayAgg(
        "students__name",
        filter=Q(students__name__icontains="d")
    )
)

for row in qs:
    print(row)
    print(row.names)

>>> Course('Agg-ravating Queries')
>>> ['Woody', 'Sid']
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since the question is required to get the list of items from related object from all relevant records in same table.